# How to insert character into set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a small game which starts with a menu and the player can choose between 6 options. The decision from the player will be written with a `cin` into a `char` variable. This works fine, and the game starts with the option.
But the game also starts when the player enter another value and then the game has errors.
To fix it, I wanted to use a character set with the possible options. But on every way I try to insert values into the set variable I get a compiler error.

When I try to initialize set while declaring I get *"'a' was not declared in this scope"*:

```
set <char> Options {a,b};
```

If I try it like this, *"no matching function for call to 'std::set::insert(const char [2])'|"*

```
set <char> Options {"a","b"};
```

When I do it like this, I get also *"'a' was not declared in this scope"*

```
set <char> Options;

int main()

Options.insert(a);
```

I also tried this, but then again I get *"no matching function for call to 'std::set::insert(const char [2])'"*

```
set <char> Options;

int main()

Options.insert("a");
```

So now I'm very confused. With integer I have no problems, but when I try to use it with characters, I didn't get it working.

Can somebody help?

(This is my first question here, I hope it's well formulated)

Comment: Double quotes indicate a string, use single quotes to denote a character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character literals are spelled with apostrophes:

```
set<char> Options {'a', 'b'};
//                 ^^^  ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i didn't know!